# Input text will appear when certain checkbox is checked. And will be hidden when uncheck

Tags: jquery, checkbox

So, there are four checkboxes... Heating, AC, Cold Chain, and Others.

When "Others" is checked, the hidden input text will appear with a placeholder "Please specify"... and when it is unchecked, the input text box will on "display none".

Note that the other values (Heating, AC, Cold Chain) use the same input text box.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(displayCheckbox);

CountSelectedCB = [];

function displayCheckbox(){    
    $("input:checkbox").change(function() {          
        selectedCB = [];
        notSelectedCB = [];
        selectedValue=$(this).attr("value");
        
        CountSelectedCB.length = 0;
        
         if(selectedValue==="Others" && $(this).is(":checked")){
                  uncheckAllCheckBox();
                   $(this).prop('checked', true);
                    CountSelectedCB.push(selectedValue);
         }
         else{
         $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
         if($(this).attr("value")==="Others")
              $(this).prop('checked', false);
              
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                CountSelectedCB.push($(this).attr("value"));
            }
        });
         }         
        
        
        $('input[name=solutions]').val(CountSelectedCB).blur();
    });
}

function uncheckAllCheckBox(){
 $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
       $(this).prop('checked', false);
       CountSelectedCB.length=0;
 });
}

$(document).ready(displayRadiobox);

CountSelectedRB = [];

function displayRadiobox(){    
    $("input:radio").change(function() {          
        selectedRB = [];
        notSelectedRB = [];
        
        CountSelectedRB.length = 0;
        $("input:radio").each(function() {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                CountSelectedRB.push($(this).attr("value"));
            }
        });
        
        $('input[name=existing]').val(CountSelectedRB).blur(); 
    });
} 


$('#solutions, #existing').bind('keyup blur', function() {
        
    $('#summary').val('You are looking for solutions in ' + 
                             $('#solutions').val() + 
                             (' \n') +
                             'Are you using an existing customer? ' + 
                             $('#existing').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> Looking for a solutions in:<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="Heating">Heating<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="Ac">AC<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="Cold Chain">Cold Chain<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="Others">Others<br>
</div>
<input name="specify" type="text" id="specify" style="display: none">
<input name="solutions" type="text" id="solutions">


<div><br>Are you an exisiting customer?<br>
<input type="radio" value="Yes" name="radio">Yes<br>
<input type="radio" value="No" name="radio">No
</div>

<input name="existing" type="text" id="existing">
<br><br>
Summary:<br>
<textarea type='text' id="summary"></textarea>
```

Comment: And what's your issue? What's the intended behavior? (I guessed it, but you have to answer these two questions in your post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that the `input` with the id `#specify` is not showing when you select "Other".

I've added this code:

```
$("#specify").attr("placeholder","Please specify").show();
$("#solutions").hide();
```

Is this what you want?

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(displayCheckbox);

CountSelectedCB = [];

function displayCheckbox() {       
  $("input:checkbox").change(function() {                 
    selectedCB = [];        
    notSelectedCB = [];
    selectedValue = $(this).attr("value");                
    CountSelectedCB.length = 0;

    if (selectedValue === "Others" && $(this).is(":checked")) {
      uncheckAllCheckBox();
      $(this).prop('checked', true);
      CountSelectedCB.push(selectedValue);
      $("#specify").attr("placeholder","Please specify").show();
      $("#solutions").hide();
    } else {
      $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("value") === "Others")
          $(this).prop('checked', false);

        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
          CountSelectedCB.push($(this).attr("value"));
        }
      });
      $("#specify").hide();
      $("#solutions").show();
    }                        
    $('input[name=solutions]').val(CountSelectedCB).blur();    
  });
}

function uncheckAllCheckBox() {
  $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
    CountSelectedCB.length = 0;
  });
}

$(document).ready(displayRadiobox);

CountSelectedRB = [];

function displayRadiobox() {       
  $("input:radio").change(function() {                 
    selectedRB = [];        
    notSelectedRB = [];                
    CountSelectedRB.length = 0;        
    $("input:radio").each(function() {            
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {                
        CountSelectedRB.push($(this).attr("value"));            
      }        
    });                
    $('input[name=existing]').val(CountSelectedRB).blur();     
  });
}


$('#solutions, #existing').bind('keyup blur', function() {            
  $('#summary').val('You are looking for solutions in ' +                               $('#solutions').val() +                               (' \n') +                              'Are you using an existing customer? ' +                               $('#existing').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> Looking for a solutions in:<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Heating">Heating<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Ac">AC<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Cold Chain">Cold Chain<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Others">Others<br>
</div>
<input name="specify" type="text" id="specify" style="display: none">
<input name="solutions" type="text" id="solutions">


<div><br>Are you an exisiting customer?<br>
  <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="radio">Yes<br>
  <input type="radio" value="No" name="radio">No
</div>

<input name="existing" type="text" id="existing">
<br><br> Summary:
<br>
<textarea type='text' id="summary"></textarea>
```

Comment: Almost! It's just that the input text id solutions will be display none if "others" is unchecked

Comment: @sueshi don't it do that if you run my demo, If you select other, then `#solutions` is hidden

Comment: @sueshi No problem, happy to help

Comment: can you help identify css selector for jquery? So, there's a div with id = solution and inside is the input text with name = solutions. So, I'm thinking of calling the div and input to show... $("div#solution:input[name=solutions").attr("placeholder","Please specify").show();

Comment: @sueshi I think it has to look like `$("div#solution input[name=solutions]").attr("placeholder","Please specify").show()`, btw if the answer solved the question please mark it so others know that it solved your problems